# complex.h workaround in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

After some searching I've found that Microsoft Visual Studio does not provide the "complex.h" header file, but I have some C code that unfortunately uses it. I've tried using `<complex>` and compiling as C++ code; this requires changing

```
complex
```

to

```
_complex
```

I don't even know what I would need to change

```
long complex
```

to. Any ideas how I can get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this link](http://www.download3k.com/Software-Development/Components-Libraries/Download-CMATH-for-Visual-C.html)?

---

If you can't use third-party libraries, then I think you're going to be compelled to re-implement complex functionality yourself.   The good news is that most complex math is actually really simple to write, unless you need some fairly advanced features.

Comment: This is commercial software, so using third-party libraries is not the best option due to licensing issues.